# Android HttpClient sending rst packet during execute

Tags: java, android, multithreading, apache-commons-httpclient

I have encountered a rather befuddling conundrum when attempting to use an `HttpClient` in my application. Seemingly at random, `HttpClient.execute(HttpRequest)` will never return! Well... if I set a timeout using `HttpConnectionParams.setConnectionTimeout(HttpParams, int)` it will throw a timeout exception. Otherwise my background thread will hang forever.

I tried everything under the sun to remedy the issue, but to no avail. Left with no alternatives I took a packet capture of the issue and found something surprising! (Or maybe not so surprising, I'm not really a network guy)

Successful call:

```
 905 75.286537   192.168.20.163        192.168.20.171        TCP      74     34340 > http [SYN] Seq=0 Win=5840 Len=0 MSS=1460 SACK_PERM=1 TSval=411399 TSecr=0 WS=16
 906 75.286634   192.168.20.171        192.168.20.163        TCP      74     http > 34340 [SYN, ACK] Seq=0 Ack=1 Win=8192 Len=0 MSS=1260 WS=256 SACK_PERM=1 TSval=2129684 TSecr=411399
 919 78.280782   192.168.20.163        192.168.20.171        TCP      74     34340 > http [SYN] Seq=0 Win=5840 Len=0 MSS=1460 SACK_PERM=1 TSval=411783 TSecr=0 WS=16
 920 78.286704   192.168.20.171        192.168.20.163        TCP      74     http > 34340 [SYN, ACK] Seq=0 Ack=1 Win=8192 Len=0 MSS=1260 WS=256 SACK_PERM=1 TSval=2129984 TSecr=411399
 955 84.280710   192.168.20.163        192.168.20.171        TCP      74     34340 > http [SYN] Seq=0 Win=5840 Len=0 MSS=1460 SACK_PERM=1 TSval=412551 TSecr=0 WS=16
 956 84.287958   192.168.20.171        192.168.20.163        TCP      70     http > 34340 [SYN, ACK] Seq=0 Ack=1 Win=65535 Len=0 MSS=1260 SACK_PERM=1 TSval=2130584 TSecr=411399
 957 84.288332   192.168.20.163        192.168.20.171        TCP      66     34340 > http [ACK] Seq=1 Ack=1 Win=93440 Len=0 TSval=412551 TSecr=2130584
 959 84.648812   192.168.20.163        192.168.20.171        TCP      294    [TCP segment of a reassembled PDU]
 960 84.649333   192.168.20.163        192.168.20.171        HTTP     411    POST /xxxxx.Service/xxxxx.asmx/GetReservations HTTP/1.1  (application/json)
 961 84.649368   192.168.20.171        192.168.20.163        TCP      66     http > 34340 [ACK] Seq=1 Ack=574 Win=16630272 Len=0 TSval=2130620 TSecr=412598
 962 84.656518   192.168.20.171        192.168.20.163        TCP      1314   [TCP segment of a reassembled PDU]
 963 84.656560   192.168.20.171        192.168.20.163        HTTP     580    HTTP/1.1 200 OK  (application/json)
 964 84.657192   192.168.20.163        192.168.20.171        TCP      66     34340 > http [ACK] Seq=574 Ack=1249 Win=119808 Len=0 TSval=412599 TSecr=2130621
 965 84.686906   192.168.20.163        192.168.20.171        TCP      66     34340 > http [ACK] Seq=574 Ack=1764 Win=159744 Len=0 TSval=412603 TSecr=2130621
 968 85.187509   192.168.20.163        192.168.20.171        TCP      66     34340 > http [FIN, ACK] Seq=574 Ack=1764 Win=159744 Len=0 TSval=412667 TSecr=2130621
 969 85.187567   192.168.20.171        192.168.20.163        TCP      66     http > 34340 [ACK] Seq=1764 Ack=575 Win=16630272 Len=0 TSval=2130674 TSecr=412667
```

Failing call:

```
2653 195.296440  192.168.20.163        192.168.20.171        TCP      74     60962 > http [SYN] Seq=0 Win=5840 Len=0 MSS=1460 SACK_PERM=1 TSval=426761 TSecr=0 WS=16
2656 195.296894  192.168.20.171        192.168.20.163        TCP      74     http > 60962 [SYN, ACK] Seq=0 Ack=1 Win=8192 Len=0 MSS=1260 WS=256 SACK_PERM=1 TSval=2141685 TSecr=426761
2658 195.297191  192.168.20.163        192.168.20.171        TCP      66     60962 > http [ACK] Seq=1 Ack=1 Win=5840 Len=0 TSval=426761 TSecr=2141685
2659 195.669276  192.168.20.163        192.168.20.171        TCP      294    [TCP segment of a reassembled PDU]
2660 195.669749  192.168.20.163        192.168.20.171        HTTP     411    POST /xxxxx.Service/xxxxx.asmx/GetReservations HTTP/1.1  (application/json)
2661 195.669783  192.168.20.171        192.168.20.163        TCP      66     http > 60962 [ACK] Seq=1 Ack=574 Win=66048 Len=0 TSval=2141722 TSecr=426809
2662 195.670095  192.168.20.163        192.168.20.171        TCP      60     60962 > http [RST] Seq=574 Win=0 Len=0
2802 215.154316  192.168.20.163        192.168.20.171        TCP      74     48450 > http [SYN] Seq=0 Win=5840 Len=0 MSS=1460 SACK_PERM=1 TSval=429303 TSecr=0 WS=16
2803 215.154397  192.168.20.171        192.168.20.163        TCP      74     http > 48450 [SYN, ACK] Seq=0 Ack=1 Win=8192 Len=0 MSS=1260 WS=256 SACK_PERM=1 TSval=2143671 TSecr=429303
2804 215.154704  192.168.20.163        192.168.20.171        TCP      60     48450 > http [RST] Seq=1 Win=0 Len=0
2807 215.716852  192.168.20.163        192.168.20.171        TCP      66     60962 > http [FIN, ACK] Seq=574 Ack=1 Win=5840 Len=0 TSval=429375 TSecr=2141685
2826 218.152321  192.168.20.163        192.168.20.171        TCP      74     48450 > http [SYN] Seq=0 Win=5840 Len=0 MSS=1460 SACK_PERM=1 TSval=429687 TSecr=0 WS=16
2827 218.152387  192.168.20.171        192.168.20.163        TCP      74     [TCP Previous segment lost] http > 48450 [SYN, ACK] Seq=821395 Ack=1 Win=8192 Len=0 MSS=1260 WS=256 SACK_PERM=1 TSval=2143970 TSecr=429687
2828 218.152669  192.168.20.163        192.168.20.171        TCP      60     48450 > http [RST] Seq=1 Win=0 Len=0
2957 224.152259  192.168.20.163        192.168.20.171        TCP      74     48450 > http [SYN] Seq=0 Win=5840 Len=0 MSS=1460 SACK_PERM=1 TSval=430455 TSecr=0 WS=16
2958 224.152379  192.168.20.171        192.168.20.163        TCP      74     [TCP Previous segment lost] http > 48450 [SYN, ACK] Seq=1936893 Ack=1 Win=8192 Len=0 MSS=1260 WS=256 SACK_PERM=1 TSval=2144570 TSecr=430455
2959 224.152722  192.168.20.163        192.168.20.171        TCP      60     48450 > http [RST] Seq=1 Win=0 Len=0
3032 230.130084  192.168.20.163        192.168.20.171        TCP      639    [TCP Retransmission] 60962 > http [FIN, PSH, ACK] Seq=1 Ack=1 Win=5840 Len=573 TSval=431220 TSecr=2141685
```

The weirdness starts at line 2662 when for no apparent reason, my device sends a RST packet to the server? Why on earth would it do that? You can see the termination of the connection that occurs at packet 2802 ~20s later (which is my timeout value). The thing is, when the device sends the RST packet `HttpClient.execute` doesn't return, it just sits there!

Maybe I missed something when configuring my client?

```
private static DefaultHttpClient newClient()
{
    HttpParams params = new BasicHttpParams();

    ConnManagerParams.setMaxConnectionsPerRoute(params, new ConnPerRouteBean(30));
    ConnManagerParams.setMaxTotalConnections(params, 100);

    HttpProtocolParams.setContentCharset(params, HTTP.DEFAULT_CONTENT_CHARSET);
    HttpProtocolParams.setUseExpectContinue(params, false);
    HttpProtocolParams.setUserAgent(params, "XXXXX XXXXXXXXXX/1.0");
    HttpProtocolParams.setVersion(params, HttpVersion.HTTP_1_1);

    HttpConnectionParams.setConnectionTimeout(params, SOCKET_OPERATION_TIMEOUT);
    HttpConnectionParams.setSoTimeout(params, SOCKET_OPERATION_TIMEOUT);
    HttpConnectionParams.setSocketBufferSize(params, 8192);
    HttpConnectionParams.setStaleCheckingEnabled(params, true);

    SchemeRegistry reg = new SchemeRegistry();
    reg.register(new Scheme("http", PlainSocketFactory.getSocketFactory(), 80));
    reg.register(new Scheme("https", SSLSocketFactory.getSocketFactory(), 443));
    ThreadSafeClientConnManager mgr = new ThreadSafeClientConnManager(params, reg);

    DefaultHttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient(mgr, params);

    return client;
}
```

Or maybe it has to do with how I issue the request?

```
private JSONObject performRequest(String url, JSONObject values) 
        throws ClientProtocolException, IOException, JSONException {
    HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);
    httpPost.setHeader("content-type", "application/json");
    httpPost.setHeader(HTTP.CONN_DIRECTIVE,HTTP.CONN_CLOSE);

    StringEntity requestEntity;
    requestEntity = new StringEntity(values.toString(), HTTP.UTF_8);
    httpPost.setEntity(requestEntity);

    HttpResponse response;
    HttpEntity responseEntity = null;
    String responseString;
    try {
        //this is the line that never returns
        response = _httpClient.execute(httpPost);
        responseEntity = response.getEntity();          
        responseString = EntityUtils.toString(responseEntity);
    } finally {
        if (responseEntity != null)
            responseEntity.consumeContent();
    }
    String d = new JSONObject(responseString).getString("d");
    if (d.length() > 0)
        return new JSONObject(d);
    else
        return new JSONObject();
}
```

The same `HttpClient` is used for all web service calls in my application and multiple threads have access to this client. I has assumed that the use of a `ThreadSafeClientConnManager` would provide the thread safety I need, but I guess there might be something else I missed.

Any help is much appreciated, I've been beating my head against the keyboard all day trying to solve this.

*edit*
I suppose I should mention this only occurs when I use a machine name as the url, not if I use the specific ip address.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out! One of the [configuration scripts](http://www.daemon-systems.org/man/dhcpcd-run-hooks.8.html) [dhcpcd](http://www.daemon-systems.org/man/dhcpcd.8.html) was running on my device was not agreeing with the hardware/drivers I was using. I modified the script and it resolved the buggy TCP/IP connections.

Answer (score 0):

I've had a very similar problem before. It turned out that I had some data in my POST body that the server didn't like. I used trial and error to eliminate what I was throwing into my HttpPost object until the request went through.

For me, I was throwing in a bad key-value pair.

In other words, I believe your problem is somewhere in your "values" object. My problem was that I had the JSON key "_b" in my POST request. Try removing JSON values until the server stops timing out.

One more tip: To test for this, I created an app that just repeatedly makes a network request, one that I know is prone to timing out, in a loop until I get the timeout. Normally I'd time out within the first 100 requests. May help if you do the same.

Comment: I can't imagine this is the issue as I see different behavior between two identical requests.

Comment: If you are seeing different behaviour, then by definition there must be a difference between the requests. Can you provide examples of the requests you are making?

Comment: The issue is not on the web service, the issue is the device terminating the connection mid request. This happens inconsistently from call to call.